# dbforge смог, а mySQL и VS2005 только старается...помогите!

Tags: mysql, windows, visual-studio, mysqlconnector

Есть домен в компании, настроенный на работу под windowsXP. Админы пророчили невозможность работы в ней под windows 10, я уперто ее поставил все отлично работает. Поставил VS2005, SQLSMS2005 и dbforge(умничка). При подключении в домене к БД все отлично! Но как только нужно сделать подключение к БД вне домена, тут SQL и VS2005(с рабочей строкой подклчения на другом ПК) выдают ошибку: 26!!!! А dbForge как ни в чем не бывало подключается!! У кого есть догадки???? Помогите!!!

Comment: Так MySQL или SQL Server? Ни VS, ни SQLSMS вроде не умеют работать с MySQL. Покажите пример строки подключения, с которой выдает ошибку.

Comment: Я поключаюсь с помощью SQLSMS к SQL server 2005
Data Source=192.168.2.*, 3788; Connect Timeout=5000; Pooling=false;  Initial Catalog=PE; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****";
Все разрешения выставил и брандмаузеры отключил

Comment: В конфигурации SQL Server на машине, к которой вы подключаетесь, в протоколах (Диспетчер конфигурации - Сетевая конфигурация SQL Server - Протоколы для...)  включен TCP/IP?

Comment: Да, включено...

Comment: Опишите подробнее конфигурацию сети. Ваша машина - Windows 10 в домене, а 192.168.2.* - обычный сервер в рабочей группе? Какая на нем ОС? Какая ОС на контроллере домена?

Comment: Ваша машина Windows 10 в домене  - ДА 
192.168.2.* - в другом домене(в другом городе) любая другая машина работает без проблем, но моя под vs2005 и SQLSMS не коннектится, а dbForge спокойно подключается.
192.168.2.*  - На нем стоит windows server 2003 x64 
На обоих контроллер доменах стоит windows server 2003(они общаются)

Еще одна связанная с этим же проблема - у нас есть еще сервер на хостинге с которым аналогичная проблема VS, SQL, не может, а dbForge может подкл.

Comment: Ничего не остается, как только сносить маздай и накатывать заново(((((((((((((

Comment: Я не думаю, что переустановка поможет. Вместо этого, лучше бы установить что-то вроде WireShark и изучать трафик между компьютерами при неудачной попытке установления соединения: какие протоколы используются и какие ошибки возвращаются. Похоже на сетевую проблему (хотя SQL 2005 - очень старый софт, и он может быть просто несовместим с Windows 10; я пробовал на нее ставить максимум SQLSMS2008, она работала).

Comment: Мда странно, а ведь с другими БД в сети все норм работает. Тут даже не так важен sql как студия 2005!